# Inequality with infimum and supremum for $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Is it true that if $$A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$ then $$ \sup A - \inf A \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sup A_n -  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \inf A_n \quad (\star)$$

I suppose that it is true (I need it to other proof). I suppose that we have $$\sup A \le \sup \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sup A_n$$ What can I say about infimum? We have $$\inf A \ge  \inf \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)$$ but of course  $$\inf \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sup A_n $$

Could you give me some hints how can I get $(\star)$?

Comment: Relating the supremum of the union to the sum of suprema, as you have done, is utterly wrong. Where do you get that idea from?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

Take $A = \{{0,1,10,11\}}$, $A_1 = \{{0,1\}}$, $A_2 =\{{10,11\}}$, $A_3 = A_4 = \dots = \{{0\}}$. Then the LHS of $(\star)$ is $11$ and the RHS is $2$, so $(\star)$ is not satisfied.