# Why is the sequence $u_N = \inf\{s_n : n \gt N\}$ increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

A question in my book I am studying says to let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be sequences and suppose there exists $N_0$ such that $s_n \le t_n$ for all $n \gt N_0$. Show $\lim \inf s_n \le \lim \inf t_n$ and $\lim \sup s_n \le \lim \sup t_n$.

The hint for the problem  in the back of my book says to let $u_N = \inf \{s_n : n \gt N\}$ and $w_N = \inf \{t_n : n \gt N\}$. Then it says that $u_N$ and $w_N$ are increasing sequences and $u_N \le w_N$ for all $N \gt N_0$.

What I don't understand is how we can assume that $u_N$ and $w_N$ are increasing sequences. From my understanding, since we don't explicitly know what $s_n$ and $t_n$, we cannot know if these are increasing or decreasing right? Also would they still be increasing if it was defined instead as $u_N = \sup\{s_n : n \gt N\}$?

Comment: Because $u_N=\inf\{u_{N+1},s_{N+1}\}$ hence $u_N\leqslant u_{N+1}$.

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sup A\le \sup B$. This was already explained in the grand_chat's answer, I will add some links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623383/inequality-with-infimum-and-supremum-for-a-subseteq-bigcup-n-1-inftya-n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528089/show-that-if-a-subseteq-b-then-inf-b-leq-inf-a-leq-sup-a-leq-sup-b

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the inf of a set of real numbers is the *greatest* lower bound. This means that for any set $S$ we have:

(1) $x\ge \inf S$ for every $x\in S$, and

(2) if $b$ is a lower bound for $S$ (i.e., $x\ge b$ for every $x\in S$), then $\inf S\ge b$.

From (1) and (2) we can prove:

**Fact 1:** If set $A$ is contained in set $B$, then $\inf A\ge\inf B$.

**Proof:**  For every $x\in A$, we have $x\in B$, since $A$ is a subset of $B$. So by (1), $x\ge \inf B$ for every $x\in A$. Therefore $\inf B$ is a lower bound for set $A$. So by (2), $\inf A\ge\inf B$.

What does this have to do with your question? Note that the set
$$\{s_n:n>N+1\}$$
is contained in the set
$$
\{s_n:n>N\}$$
and therefore
$$u_{N+1}:=\inf\{s_n:n>N+1\}\ge\inf\{s_n:n>N\}=:u_N.$$

Therefore the $\{u_N\}$ form an increasing sequence (actually, non-decreasing). And if we were taking sups instead of infs, the sequences of sups would be decreasing (actually, non-increasing), because of

**Fact 2:** If set $A$ is contained in set $B$, then $\sup A\le\sup B$.

which you should be able to prove analogously to Fact 1. The intuition behind facts 1 and 2 is: When a set loses elements, the inf can only get bigger, while the sup can only get smaller.